# How to add custom configs variables to custom shipping method?

Tags: magento-2.1, module, shipping-methods, custom-variable

I have created a custom shipping method following this tutorial:

> https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/

Now I would need to add a couple of extra variables to admin configuration, and save it in any place to use it later when the checkout is done. 
How can I do that?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to add some configuration In STORES > Configuration -> SALES section -> Shipping Methods ??

Comment: hey @AdityaShah. Yes I would want that. Really I need to save a couple of config data to use it later in the checkout process, I think this is a good place, but it  also could be in other place.

Comment: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-custom-shipping-module-magento-2/

Answer (score 0):

You can add more field like below in your `system.xml` under `group` tag with `id="simpleshipping"` in above module-

```
<field id="custom_variable" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
      <label>Custom Variable</label>
</field>
```

Now you can retrieve value of this field in any file like block or model or controller like this --

```
protected $_scopeConfig;

public function __construct(
     ...
     \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface $scopeInterface,
     ...
)
{
    ...
    $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeInterface;
    ...
}
```

Then in your class' method you can call the following:

```
$this->scopeConfig->getValue('carriers/simpleshipping/custom_variable', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Shashank, let me try this option.

Comment: ok @DanielSilva , let me know in case of any error